# example of recursive algorithm in java with Θ( log n)

Tags: algorithm, recursion, code-analysis, big-o

I was looking for many days, I had try many recursive algorithm examples but I couldn'd find any algorithm that have `Θ( log n )` running time.
 Do you know any recursice algorithm in java that have  a function `T(n) = Θ( log n )`. 
 Where `T(n)` is  function that express the number of  time the basic operation of the algoritm is executed.
 Any help with be very appreciated.
thanks!

Comment: [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) has the specified asymptotic bound (on worst case input) if you write it recursively. You can use the master theorem to prove.

Comment: Exponentiation modulo m by recursive halving the exponent and squaring the result.

Answer (score 1):

As one example, consider finding the biggest integer exponent `e` of a integer `m` such that m<sup>e</sup> | n, for some integer `n`:

```
findBiggestExponent(int n, int m)
{
    if(n % m == 0)
        return 1 + findBiggestExponent(n/m, m);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Clearly `e <= log n` holds. And since the recursive algorithm computes `e` as a sum of one's, the complexity of the algorithm is `O(log n)`.